# Compiling Stylus Files while scaffolding with Yeoman

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, scaffolding, stylus

I've got my own generators which work like charms.

One thing I'd like to add to them that would make my work faster is to compile stylus file once they have been copied to the new project folder. Is there a way to achieve this with Yeoman without the user being forced to launch grunt after the yo command?

Thank you!
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just have the compiled CSS in this case anyway? If the Yo process can install npm dependencies then you should be able to execute a script that will compile the stylus files.